# How to use/link source code as a library (C/C++)

Tags: c, build, linker, sdl, static-libraries

I'm trying to understand how to use build and use source code and then link to it in my project. Specifically I'm trying to do this with the SDL2 library. I am on a mac and want to do this in the command line (I am not using xcode).

- I've downloaded the source code (which you can find here: https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), and put the folder into the same directory as my main.c file.
- I cd'd into this directory and run the following commands `./configure` and then `make`.
- Next, I *can* run the command `make install` which puts the library into my usr/bin directory. Then, I *can* link to this library in the command line like this `clang main.c -o main -lSDL2` but I'm trying to understand how to not do this step and link to the code in my application directory.

I've been trying to run commands like this:

```
clang main.c -o main -L./SDL2/build/.libs -I./SDL2/include -lSDL2
```

```
clang main.c -o main -L./SDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2
```

My thought process was that the -L flag tells where the built code should be to link to, because in the ./SDL2/build/.libs folder I see the files called libSDL2.a, libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib, and libSDL2.dylib.
These commands actually do succesfully build and I get a `main` output file, but when I try to run that file I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jerfp/Documents/personal/c-stuff/sdl-test-source/./main
  Reason: image not found
[1]    37284 abort      ./main
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or why it's looking for the library in /usr/local/lib/ when I have specified a different path with the -L flag.

Also to note, in my main.c file, I'm including the sdl header like this:

```
#include "SDL2/include/SDL.h"
```

since that is the folder path to the SDL.h file. I'm also not certain that this is correct, but is what I'm doing at the moment.

Any help here would be very apprecatied. I'm new to C and just trying to understand how linking/building/including libraries works without installing them with something like homebrew or make install.

Here is the compiler I'm using:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a dynamic library, you have to specify a search path both at build-time *and* at run-time. The `-L` flag tells your linker at build-time where to find the library, but within the executable, the symbol table will list symbols from dynamic libraries as undefined, meaning there is no memory address associated with those symbols. At run-time, the dynamic linker has to find those same libraries in order to load the executable. The simplest way to provide this path to the dynamic linker is using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable at runtime (on Mac it might be `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./SDL2/build/.libs ./main
```

You can also embed the library path into the executable, though this assumes that your libraries will be at a predictable location every time you run the executable. To do this, you use the `-rpath` linker flag, which will create a `DT_RUNPATH` entry in the `.dynamic` section of the executable (don't worry if you don't know what all of that means). For relative paths, you can use the special value, `$ORIGIN`, to refer to the directory containing the executable. In your case, the command would look something like this (note the use of `-Wl`, which tells `clang` that this flag should be passed to the underlying linker):

```
clang -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/SDL2/build/.libs' main.o -o main -L./SDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2
```

Then you should be able to run the executable with no special environment variables:

```
./main
```

Comment: Does `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` work on Mac? I was under impression that they use something else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think you are right, I'll update the answer

Comment: @TallChuck Thank you so, so much, I really appreciate it and I am learning a lot from your answer. One followup question though, when I try running the command you provided I get this error message:

Comment: duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-6b8b9a.o
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-ffe3b3.o
duplicate symbol '_SCREEN_HEIGHT' in:
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-6b8b9a.o
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-ffe3b3.o
duplicate symbol '_SCREEN_WIDTH' in:
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-6b8b9a.o
    /var/folders/8d/f8cxy_k54t35ylph82ydnwxw0000gp/T/main-ffe3b3.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: Might you know why/how I can avoid these duplicate symbol errors?

Comment: @jerfp what's the exact command you are using?

Comment: @TallChuck clang main.c -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/SDL2/build/.libs' main.c -o main -L./SDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2

Comment: @jerfp you are including `main.c` twice

Comment: @jerfp I see that I made that mistake in the answer, I'll correct it

Comment: @TallChuck Oh shoot I was. I removed the second main.c and it builds, but not when I run ./ main I get this error:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jpalmeri/Documents/personal/c-stuff/sdl-test-source/./main
  Reason: image not found
[1]    53762 abort      ./main

Comment: It's looking in usr/local/lib for some reason?

Comment: really what you should do is to first compile `clang -I./SDL2/include -c -o main.o main.c` and then link it with `clang -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/SDL2/build/.libs' main.o -o main -L./SDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242957/discussion-between-tallchuck-and-jerfp).